# How can I migrate an Azure application to IIS?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have a webrole I'd like to host in IIS for the time being.

Does anyone know how involved this is, considering that I still want Azure Storage functions of the IIS site to still work?

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify your question a little bit: do you want to run the site on Windows Azure using full IIS, or do you want to run it completely outside the Windows Azure environment (on premise, at a hosting company, etc.)?

Comment: I'd like to host it on-premise...

Comment: I just answered another similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63516086/6732525

Comment: I just answered another similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63516086/6732525

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure Storage (tables, blobs, queues) only run on the actual Windows Azure environment in the cloud. There is a *simulated* development environment that runs a facsimile on a local SQL Server database, but that is only meant for development purposes and cannot be used for running an actual site.

Theoretically, you could run your webapp locally and connect to Azure Storage over the internet (e.g. by using the REST api), but latency would almost certainly be too high for any interactive site.

So, if you want to be able to run your site on premise on your own IIS environment, you will need to remove all the specific Azure platform dependencies and build in non-Azure alternatives. For Azure Storage, you could either do a relational database (SQL Server, mySQL) or look at a nosql/document database.

Comment: I've configured my web application to run within IIS locally. This allows us to work with a shorter edit/build/debug cycle. It's also nice when working with Views because you can edit in-place and immediately see changes.

You can use the RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable property to detect if you are running within the Azure environment and skip certain calls if needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move it to IIS then tijmedvdk's answer is correct.

If your goal is to run it in your data center then you should consider Azure Appliance http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/appliance/ this allows you to run Azure applications on premise, without making any changes.

Comment: Wow. I didn't know that existed. Still that look large scale (100's of server) only. I wonder if it will be priced to an anti-competitive level.

Answer (score 1):

This answers seems misleading. Windows Azure is a platform that provides several services and you can choose from the services that you want to use.
In essence a Windows Azure is just a Virtual Machine with
*Windows Server 2008 R2
*IIS 7.5

So can if you have an application that you are currently hosting in Azure and you want to host it in IIS I don't see much of a problem there.
If you are using Storage, the only problem might be that the Storage account settings were in the WebRole or Service configuration files, but you can change your app logic to take the appropiate settings from other config files.
I have created Windows Desktop applications that for several reasons use Azure Storage and i also think of that as a great advantage of cloud computing.