# How to deploy the Azure Functions (.Net 6.0 isolated LTS) on premises IIS?

Tags: iis, azure-functions, asp.net-core-6.0

I have created a HttpTrigger Azure function (.Net 6.0 Isolated-LTS) using Visual Studio 2022. I have published the Project in a Local Folder in my system. Try to deploy the generated dlls in the Local IIS and call the API from browser but getting error.

I have done all the steps provided in following link:
[Is it possible to deploy the Azure Functions in Local IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47325106/is-it-possible-to-deploy-the-azure-functions-in-local-iis)

I have installed **Azure Function Runtime** and set processPath in web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore" />
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.dll" hostingModel="InProcess">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="AzureWebJobsStorage" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I am still getting the following error:

***HTTP Error 500.0 - ASP.NET Core IIS hosting failure (in-process)***

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/hybrid/azure-functions-hybrid#running-azure-functions-on-premises Microsoft only supports a few options to run Azure Functions on premise. The thread you linked refer to an undocumented way, so following such is at your own risks.

Comment: Check the IIS Event Viewer for errors to get more Info. You are getting an exception in the IIS. The issue may be you are trying to access the IIS file system and do not have the credentials to access the file system. Did you do a publish and install the setup.exe folder? A Net application will only run on a deploy machine if the version of Net is same on both build and remote machine. So the core version has to be the same. You can also add to the body of the response the Stack Trace for the exception so you can determine the exact cause of issue.